# error while uploading an ASP site - cant access class

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, class, hosting

i've uploaded my ASP.NET site to an hosting server.
while i used the visual studio compailer - there were no errors.

now i get the following error when the code tries to access the class:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request.         Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'vSQL' could not be found (are you missing a     using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 32: 
Line 33:             string checkActivity = "SELECT Count(*) FROM activity WHERE activityCode=" +    activityID.Text + ";";
Line 34:             vSQL checkSqlActivitys = new vSQL();
Line 35:             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Line 36:             ds = checkSqlActivitys.sqlRet(x, checkActivity);
```

what do i need to change/add?

Comment: is vSQL in a separate DLL? Did it make it onto the server?

Comment: If vSQL is dll, add reference of it to the current projetc

Comment: how do i write the referance ?